# Passing multiple AJAX call data parameters to MVC controller goes wrong?

Tags: c#, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on an app which has to send a serialized form AND an Id to a MVC controller, which handles some things which aren't important right now.

First thing to show is my submit method, which serializes the form and sends both the id and the serialized form:

```
$("form").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: '<%= Url.Action("SaveAudit") %>',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { form: $("form").serialize(), id: auditId }
        });
    });
```

As you can see, just the normal things to send multiple data parameters. Everything goes well here and this is the POST data as been shown in my FireBug:

[image: As you can see the parameters are both filled with the right data]

As you can see the parameters are both filled with the right data...

Until I debug my MVC controller and check what's inside both my 'form' and 'id' parameter.

This is the result:

[image]

As you guys can see 'id' is filled with the right data, as 'form' is filled with data I can't refer to? **The data which 'form' is filld with isn't the serialized form which was send to the 'form' parameter in the POST** , what did I do wrong and what caused this to happen? I tried everything already but still result.

Thanks in advance?

Comment: Don't use `FormCollection` - the parameter should be the model your serializing

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587402/deserialize-jquery-serialized-form